# How fast would you have to run to create a mirror image?

Tags: optics, speed, vision, perception

So I was watching The Flash and in the most recent episode he runs so fast that he is able to create a mirror image of himself so that it looks like there is more of him than there actually is. So I guess my question has two parts. First, is this even theoretically possible and second how fast would The Flash have to run to achieve this?

Comment: LOL! I think that the "multiple mirror image" phenomenon that you may see in comic books and cartoons is a result of science fiction combined with some artistic license.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured.  Thought I would check just to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a physics phenomenon, but a biological one - look up persistence of vision. Basically our eyes have a limited response time so if we flash two different images quickly we will see an average of both images. TV uses this to appear to give us smooth motion where in reality it is flashing images every frame.

If we assume we need a 25Hz frame rate for the effect that means each frame is 40ms long. Flash needs to stationary for most of that time otherwise we would just see a blur. Let assume he is stationary for 39ms then he has 1ms to get to his new place, wait for 39ms and return to his start position and repeat the process. If he wants to create two images of himself 1 metre apart he needs a velocity of 1000 metre per second or 2236 miles per hour (assuming he can instantly accelerate).

This isn't a mirror image though, but would appear to give two images of Flash.

Comment: I'm not sure the speed is all that important. You can see flicker up to 60+ Hz (I can see it head-on to around 75, out of my periphery at over 85 Hz, and have met people who claimed they could see it past 120 Hz). Since you'd still easily see the flicker at 25 Hz, there's no particular need to use that benchmark, although lower speeds would make it more obvious. The real issue is just going between positions quickly so we can't see the transition.

Comment: You nailed it @docPhil. You are on the right thought